# Bootstrap 4 Grid issue with Angular 4

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-4

I'm facing weird issue with the grid, I tried the same code [here](https://www.bootply.com/kmqk8tgYvF#) which is Bootstrap 3, I used same in Bootstrap 4, but I'm getting below grid structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/kmqk8tgYvF#) code you have shared is using Bootstrap 3 version and in your case you are using Bootstrap 4 There is difference between these two. Please check Documentation for bootstrap 4 [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: my bad, Thanks for your reply